# Multiple outgoing ip on one amazon ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-ip

Can i have multiple public outgoing ip on an amazon aws Instance?

I have one instance with two network interfaces and two elastic ip each one, so i can ssh to my server using both publics ips.

That's enough to get multiple public outgoing ip?

Comment: outgoing for what, web server?  yes, that's enough.

Comment: Yes it's for my web server, but i need to rotate the outgoing public ip. Do you know how can i do that?

Comment: It may be helpful to be a little more clear (and detailed) about what you want to do exactly, (and maybe even why, eg what are you trying to achieve by doing this)

Answer (score 1):

> Can i have multiple public outgoing ip on an amazon aws Instance?

Yes, though it needs to be done via a VPC as you can only assign IP per network interface.

Note: It seems a little strange to setup two public IPs for the purpose of SSHing using either, but there might be a use case for it or another reason which isn't clear.

There are some interesting articles here about working with AWS http://aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/

### Do you NEED multiple public IP Addresses

First, make sure you really need multiple public IPs

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#Why_am_I_limited_to_5_Elastic_IP_addresses

> By default, all accounts are limited to 5 Elastic IP addresses per
>   region.
>
> Q: Do I need one Elastic IP address for every instance that I have
>   running? No. You do not need an Elastic IP address for all your
>   instances. By default, every instance comes with a private IP address
>   and an internet routable public IP address.

### Elastic Network Interfaces in VPC

If you need multiple public IPs consider Elastic Network Interfaces in the Virtual Private Cloud.

http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/12/new-elastic-network-interfaces-in-the-virtual-private-cloud.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html

Comment: Well, i'm already using amazon vpc, in fact i have two Elastic Network Interfaces with one private ip each one, and Two elastic ips, the ssh was only for test the external connection to the public ips. But i want to know how i can use both elastic ip as my source ip when  the server connects to internet

Comment: You need to be more clear as to what you're asking in your question. And if you're asking for something a little unusual it can help to explain what you're actually trying to achieve.